# SQL - Get consecutively minimum numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql

Title may not make sense so I will provide some context.

I have a table, call it Movies.

A movie tuple has the values: Name, Director, Genre, Year

I'm trying to create a query that allows me to return all Directors who have never released two consecutive Horror films with more than 4 years apart.

I'm not sure where I'd begin but I'm trying to start off by creating a query that given some specific year, returns the next minimum year, so that I can check if the difference between these two is less than 4, and keep doing that for all movies.

My attempt was:

```
SELECT D1.Director 
FROM Movies D1
WHERE D1.Director NOT IN 
(SELECT D2.Director FROM Director D2 
 WHERE D2.Director = D1.Director 
 AND D2.Genre = 'Horror'
 AND D1.Genre = 'Horror' AND D2.Year - D1.Year > 4 
 OR D1.Year - D2.Year > 4)
```

which does not work for obvious reasons.

I've also had a few attempts using joins, and it works on films that follow a pattern such as 2000, 2003, 2006, but fail if more than 3 films.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

Select all data, and use lag or lead to return the last or next year.  After that look at the difference between the two.

```
WITH TempTable AS (
  SELECT
    Name,
    Director,
    Genre,
    Year,
    LAG(Year) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Director, Genre ORDER BY Year ASC) AS 'PriorYear'
  FROM
    Movies
  WHERE
    Genre = 'Horror'
)

SELECT
  Name,
  Director
FROM
  TempTable
GROUP BY
  Name,
  Director
HAVING
  MAX(Year-PriorYear) < 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How does LAG and PARTITION work - I've never actually used these 2 functions.

Comment: LAG is what is referred to as a windowed function, it works similar to RANK and ROW_NUMBER.  LAG will return the prior record (according to the ORDER BY component), LEAD will return the next record, RANK will return the ranking with ties {(1,1,2,3) => (1,1,3,4)} ROW_NUMBER will return the row number {(1,1,2,2) => (1,2,3,4)}.  Basically, PARTITION will work similar to a group by clause, meaning that rank will reset with every different combination.  This means that LAG will return the prior year for that name/director/genre and will return NULL when there is no prior record.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT director, min(diff) as diff FROM (
        SELECT m1.director, m1.year as year1, m2.year as year2, m2.year-m1.year as diff 
        FROM `movies` m1, movies m2 
        WHERE m1.director = m2.director and m1.name <> m2.name and m1.year<=m2.year 
        and m1.genre='horror' and m2.genre='horror'
    ) d1 group by director
) d2 WHERE diff>4
```

First, in the inner Select it will list all movie pairs of directors' horror movies with year difference calculated, then minimum of these are selected (for consecutiveness), then longer than 4 years differences are selected...

Comment: If there are 3 movies 2000, 2003, and 2006.  Then "FROM m1, m2" would create (2000, 2003), (2000, 2006), (2003, 2006).  Then "m1.year-m2.year" would return 3, 6, and 3.  This would suggest that the director did in fact make movies more than 4 years apart, given the 6, but those 2 are not consecutive.

Comment: @hcaelxxam this is exactly the problem I'm facing with my code but you just phrased it better.

Comment: that is why minimal diff is chosen to compare to 4!